# Clarify, with example, completeness conjecture by Pearl and Paz

Tags: conditional-probability, causality, independence, conditional-independence

I was going through *Probabilistic Reasoning In Intelligent Systems* by *Judea Pearl*. A completeness conjecture (for which no complete proof is there as yet, but has been found to be true generally, as claimed by the author) is introduced there which I want to understand with the help of a concrete example. The conjecture is as follows -

> The set of axioms in equations 1 through 4 (given below for reference)
> is complete when $I$ is interpreted as a conditional independence
> relation. In other words, for every three-place relation $I$
> satisfying equations 1 through 4, there exists a probability model $P$
> such that

$P(x|y,z)$ = $P(x|z)$    *iff*    $I(X,Z,Y)$
where $x, y$ and $z$ are configurations for the sets of variables $X,Y$ and $Z$ respectively.

***Equations:***
Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be subsets of variables from $U$
(1) **Symmetry:**
    $I(X,Z,Y)\iff I(Y,Z,X)$
(2) **Decomposition:**
    $I(X,Z,Y \cup W) \implies I(X,Z,Y) \quad I(X,Z,W)$
(2) **Weak union:**
    $I(X,Z,Y \cup W) \implies I(X,Z \cup W, Y)$
(2) **Contraction:**
    $I(X,Z,Y) \quad \& \quad I(X,Z \cup Y, W) \implies I(X,Z,W)$

**Note:** I require an example to clarify the statement of the conjecture; not a proof of it.

Comment: You have misquoted the conjecture: In your 'iff' line, it needs to be $I(X, Z, Y)$. Also, I don't really understand your question. You can easily create an example yourself. Just take e.g. the Bayesian network $A\to B\to C$, write down all the conditional independence relations thereof, and verify that they satisfy the axioms.

Comment: @frank have edited to $I(X,Z,Y)$.

As for the comment - "Just take e.g. the Bayesian network $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$, write down all the conditional independence relations thereof, and verify that they satisfy the axioms" - here when you say "write down all the conditional independence relations" do you mean those independencies implied by the graph? Like $I(A,B,C)$, because $B$ separates $A$ and $C$. Or should I be assuming a probability model alongside the network graph?

Comment: The BN describes the conditional independence relations (CIRs) of a set of pdfs and you can either read those CIRs from the graph (that's the easy way) or use one of the belonging pdfs.